# Drupal 6 - Custom page.tpl

Tags: css, drupal, drupal-6

I'm using Drupal 6. I have some css that I want to apply only for a specific content-type. The content types machine readble name is "snap".

I copied the page.tpl.php and created another file called page-snap.tpl.php.

I have restarted apache and mysql and refresh the cache but when I look for the content type snap to use as the DIV I see nothing.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Theming a page by content type](http://drupal.org/node/223440#comment-1045201)

Instructions:

- Rename `page-snap.tpl.php` to `page-node-snap.tpl.php`.
- Create a file called `template.php` in your theme folder
- 

In `template.php`, add this:

```
<?php
  function bluemarine_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
    if ($variables['node']->type == "snap") {
      $variables['template_files'][] = 'page-node-snap';
      drupal_add_css(PATH TO CSS FILE); // Enter path to custom css here
    }
  }
```

- Save the file and clear the cache (`admin/settings/performance`)

More about [`drupal_add_css()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_css/6)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry to be ignorant but where do I paste that?

Comment: In your theme folder there _might_ be a file called `template.php` (if not, create one).  Paste it into that file, then clear the cache.

Comment: Again sorry to be a moron but I can't get it to work. I created the page-snap.tpl.php. I have now created a file called template.php and pasted the code above into that. Doing that I get an error code at the top of the page that says function THEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['node']->type == "snap") {
    $variables['template_files'][] = 'page-node-snap';
  }
} all on one line. Sorry I don't normally differ from the norm when I create sites and most of the sites I have done have been very basic. Thanks

Comment: Ok, first rename `page-snap.tpl.php` to `page-node-snap.tpl.php`.  What is the name of the theme you are using?  You need to change "THEMENAME" to the name of your theme. So, if you're using Garland (example) change "function THEMENAME_preprocess_page" to "function garland_preprocess_page"

Comment: Hi, Thanks for you help. My theme is bluemarine so I changed the THEMENAME to bluemarinefunction bluemarine_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['node']->type == "snap") {
    $variables['template_files'][] = 'page-node-snap';
  }
} but I still get that error. Should the template file only have the above code? Thanks

Comment: @Andrew I have updated my answer, follow the instructions there and you should see results.

Comment: Hi, I played with this over the weekend and still can't get it to go. I looked at the link that you provided and no joy. Is there another module I need, is there a box I need to tick? I tried a clean install with no modules and I tried other themes too. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Andrew did you add a PHP tag in template.php (Do not add the closing tag)? Sorry I forgot to add that. I have edited my answer again. If it still doesn't work, I will post a link for you to download a clean install of Drupal with my changes included and instructions.

Comment: Hi, Thanks again. Maybe I'm looking in the wrong place for the results I don't know? I'm using firebug and I'm looking to see if I have a new div class called something other than "node", so far I don't see it? I've looked at other themes in the past and styled by content type etc but never done it myself I figure what you are suggesting will provide the same results. I've looked at the code in a browser and see no reference to the word "snap" so am kind of confused as to why it isn't working. Thanks again, Andrew

Comment: @Andrew What this procedure is doing is: When viewing a node of type _snap_ Drupal will use page-node-snap.tpl.php as a template. So to see results, you will need to customize page-node-snap.tpl.php however you like.  For instance, you can add a simple string such as "My Customization!" somewhere in page-node-snap.tpl.php and when viewing a snap node, you should see that string somewhere on the page.

Comment: So if I have to put in a string how does the css differentiate between a standard and a customized page. Am I not right in thinking there should be something shown in firebug? Thanks

Comment: @Andrew You are right this will show in firebug. To add css for this template, use drupal_add_css(). I have added that to my example in my answer, along with a link for its use.

Comment: @Andrew do you really want to theme the whole _page_ template or just the _node_?  If it is just the node, we can forget about some steps in my answer.

Comment: Hi, I think I've got something else going on here that I can't figure out I will do some more reading. Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$node->type` to include some additional css...

```
if($node->type == 'snap') {
  //inlcude your css file
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want different theme for different content type you can try [themekey](http://drupal.org/project/themekey) module. Using this module you can configure theme for different content types.